# can you return a string[] from ASMX to JQuery AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, asmx

Here's my web method

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string[] LoadArray()
```

Here's my javascript

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/services/Service.asmx/LoadArray',
        data: "{}",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(arr) {
            for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
                addNewPatient(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I tend to have my function return a string, and put the array of strings into one json result to pass back to the client.

Have you tried to do this?

What was the error message?

Answer (score 2):

i fixed the problem

the array should be "arr.d"